# Get Selected index of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

I want to have selected index for `UITableView`.
I have written following code:

```
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:index 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                         animated:YES];
```

This always work for 1st item. I want to have selected index in `indexPathForRow.`

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Comment: If you allow multiple selections, consider using: - (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows

Comment: Once you have that `*selectedIndexPath` it is useful for me to have access to `long pathRow = [selectedIndexPath row];` and `long pathSection = [selectedIndexPath section];` when you need specific selections (note that `NSInteger` is a `typedef long` which coming from a C background makes more sense since both need `%ld` anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Get current selected row.
May be helpful if you have only one section.

```
- (NSUInteger)currentSellectedRowIndex
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedIndexPath) {
        return selectedIndexPath.row;
    }
    else {
        return NSNotFound;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this code

```
CGPoint location =[sender locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:swipedCell];
```

Answer (score 4):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, set an interface declared NSIndexPath as the indexpath returned.  Then you can scroll to that variable.  If you need help, comment and I can give some sample code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Chris's method for quicker use.  The above method offers more control and can be modified by your (example) detail view controller.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.2

```
let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

which is an optional return value.

Comment: Straight and simple. Thanks!